# Why does jQuery only enter the function in some links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, function

I am relatively new to jQuery and JavaScript, so I'm having this issue, hope you can help me through it.

I am making an e-commerce page for selling cloths in Rails 4, so I am focusing more than I used to in the form of displaying forms and all of that, so it can be more attractive to the users. Because of that, I have the forms hidden and I set the values to it via jQuery.

The problem can be divided in two parts:

- The first part of the problem is in the cloths#show where the user add the cloth to his cart:

  **Form:**

  ```
  <%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
          <h5>Select a size</h5>
          <div class="input-sizes">
              <% @sis.each do |si| %>
                  <%= link_to si.size.letter, "#{si.size_id}", class:"normal-size" %>
              <% end %>
          </div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :size_id, id: "size-input" %>
          <h5>Select a color</h5>
          <div class="input-colors">
              <% @cos.each do |co| %>
                  <%= link_to "#{co.color_id}", id: "link-circle" do %>
                      <div id="circle" style="background: <%= co.color.hex %>">
                          <div id="mini-circle"></div>
                      </div>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
          </div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :color_id, id: "color-input" %>

          ...

  <% end %>
  ```

  **jQuery:**

  ```
  //Select size
  $('a.normal-size').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var value = $(this).attr("href");
      $('#size-input').val(value);
      $(this).removeClass("normal-size").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected").addClass("normal-size");
  });

  //Select Color
  $('#link-circle').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var value = $(this).attr("href");
      $('#color-input').val(value);
      $(this).children().children().css('opacity', '1');
      return false;
  });
  ```

  The set of the size input works perfectly but in the color input the user   only can select the first color because if the user wants to select the second, the jQuery function doesn't gets called so it goes to the link (I tried even writing `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` at the same time).
- The second part of the problem comes in the cart#show when the user can see the summary of all his cloths. In this it is displayed a table with each row being a cloth, here the user can see the image of the cloth, description, selected color, selected size and price. The color and size section is made for the user so he can edit his cloth if he changes his mind and select another size or color. The issue in here is in both size and color and I don't know why. In the color section happens exactly the same as above, but in the size section he can only make one click because if he makes another one the jQuery function doesn't get called. Is like if the click only works once:

  **Form:**

  ```
  <%= form_for (order_item), remote: true,:url => "/order_items/#{order_item.id}", :html=>{:id=>'item_form_cart'} do |f| %>
    <div class="input-colors col-md-1">
        <% @cos.each do |co| %>
            <% if co.cloth == order_item.cloth %>
                <% if co.color_id == order_item.color_id %>
                    <%= link_to "#{co.color_id}", id: "link-circle" do %>
                        <div id="circle" style="background: <%= co.color.hex %>;">
                            <div id="mini-circle" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to "#{co.color_id}", id: "link-circle" do %>
                        <div id="circle" style="background: <%= co.color.hex %>;">
                            <div id="mini-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :color_id, id: "color-input" %>
    <div class="input-sizes col-md-2">
        <% @sis.each do |si| %>
           <% if si.cloth == order_item.cloth %>
               <% if order_item.size_id == si.size_id %>
                   <%= link_to si.size.letter, "#{si.size_id}", class:"selected" %>
               <% else %>
                   <%= link_to si.size.letter, "#{si.size_id}", class:"normal-size cart-el" %>
               <% end %>
           <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :size_id, id: "size-input-cart" %>

    ...

  <% end %>
  ```

  **jQuery:**

  ```
  //Select size
  $('a.normal-size.cart-el').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var value = $(this).attr("href");
      $(this).parent().next('#size-input-cart').val(value);
      $(this).removeClass("normal-size").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected").addClass("normal-size");
      $(this).closest('#item_form_cart').submit();
  });
  ```

  In here I only make the size function because I didn't know how to fix the color one, but this also has a bug, that only gets called the first time. This happens no matter which cloth's size you select, e.i. if I change the first cloth's size works good but if I want to change again the same cloth's size or change the size of another cloth the jQuery function doesn't get called.

Hope you can help me,
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I have investigated more about why is happening the second problem and I saw that it can be related to Ajax, because in my form if a user changes the size or color it gets done by Ajax, as we can see [here](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/click-doesn-t-work-after-ajax-load-jquery/). I tried the second solution but it did not work:

```
$('.well').on('click','a.normal-size.cart-el',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).parent().next('#size-input-cart').val(value);
    $(this).removeClass("normal-size").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected").addClass("normal-size");
    $(this).closest('#item_form_cart').submit();
});

$('.well').on('click','.link-circle.cart-el',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).parent().next('#color-input-cart').val(value);
    $(this).siblings().children().children().css('opacity', '0');
    $(this).children().children().css('opacity', '1');
    $(this).closest('#item_form_cart').submit();
});
```

And here is render each item in the view:

```
<div class="order_items">
  <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
    <div class = "well">
       <%= render 'carts/cart_row', cloth: order_item.cloth, order_item: order_item, show_total: true %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select color function is attached to the id "link-circle". It looks like you're potentially rendering multiple elements with the same id. Your select size function is based on a class which you can have on multiple elements. You cannot however have the same id on multiple elements according to [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors) . Try changing "link-circle" to a class like so..

```
<%= link_to "#{co.color_id}", class: "link-circle" do %>
```

and the your selector to..

```
$('.link-circle').on('click',function(e){
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know the difference between id and class I guess this is a good one. This made the first part to work, thanks. But now I have the same problem in the carts#show as the size input, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your jquery selector is looking for an anchor element with a class of "normal-size" and "cart-el". In your call back function you're removing the "normal-size" class so the jquery selector isn't working for it anymore. You can change your selector to `$('a.cart-el')` and make sure the class "cart-el" on all your anchors.

Comment: But when I remove the `selected` class to the siblings I am adding the `normal-size`, anyway I tried what you mention and still happens the same thing, the first one works well, the others do not I have to reload the page (it seems to me like a problem with turbolinks but I have the gem that fix that). Now that the color input works, if the user change color and then try to change size the issue happens or vice versa.

Comment: If you can include the rendered html that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes of course, I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luisbarajasp/usnb7vox/) with the html and the javascript. I appreciate your help, thanks.